# PHP - PDO - Oracle and Phonegap: SESSIONS_PER_USER limit error

Tags: php, oracle, cordova, pdo, odbc

Hi stackoverflowianers!

I have a problem on using PHP, PDO, ODBC and Oracle on ServerSide and Phonegap 3 with Android on ClientSide.

For some important reasons I have to use in some cases PDO and in other cases ODBC to interact with the Oracle database.

Always after I opened a connection, I do what is to do and after that I'm closing the connection.

Now my question is:

How can it be that after some hours of testing the *Phonegap-App* I always get the odbc error:

```
odbc_connect(): SQL error: exceeded simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit in SQLConnect on line xy
```

and the PDO error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: dbh in file on line yz
```

Please help me to find out about this issue. Any idea or suggestion would be very much welcome.

Thank you in advance and best regards to you all!

Ingmar

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when the profile assigned to the user is limited to few session only and you have created sessions more than that limit.

You can check the profile name using

`select * from dba_users where USERNAME = 'your_user_name';`

And then the profile limits using
`select * from dba_profiles where profile='profile_name_from_above_query'`;

Further, if you want to make sure that you never face this error, either limit the session to the allowed limit or increase the `SESSION_PER_USER` limit.

For more information, follow [this link](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Profiles_and_password_management)

Comment: thank you very much for your fast response. Is it possible that on serverside the $dbh = null; (PDO) and the odbc_close($ora_conn); (ODBC) tags are off any reasons not working in some cases?